# Unlock Sharepoint Online file

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

Im having multiple requests to unlock files which have been locked by users (occasionally these files aren't even locked by that user). I have fond a powershell script to overcome the problem and I was wondering if someone could advise me on how I would use it please

Also how do I paste code into this forum? I used the code comment and it went all bold and out of format

[Site of code][1]

```
Testing Code
```

Comment: Type out your code, select it and then click on the curly braces in the tool bar. The coded you have referenced is for on-prem only. I'll assume by your title that you are using Office 365?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - yes I'm O365 rather than on prem... Is there a way to sort it with a hosted solution?

Comment: Given the fact that I am using SharePoint Online - am I supposed to use Get-SPOSite to retrieve SharePoint Online commandlets?

Comment: Somebody has a solution for Office 365 Sharepoint Online to unlock file locks (Releaselock) after years? I searched hours, but get no solution for Sharepoint Online (only for sharepoint on premise). Any solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had to do this in SPO as of yet but looking at the Client API I'm afraid there is no equivalent. The SOM property [locktype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.locktype) is not there and neither is the method [ReleaseLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.releaselock?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can have a look at the Client.File class members [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_members.aspx).

So to answer your question it isn't possible to release locks in SPO. If it is happening to you regularly raise a support call from your tenant admin center.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the code on one of the SharePoint servers as a user that has the rights to run the file and access each of the documents, such as the SharePoint Admin account.  First download the file to the server in a location such as `D:\scripts\` From the SharePoint Server right click 'SharePoint Management Shell' and select run as Admin.  Then run the script by typing 'D:\scripts\unlock.ps1'.  If you do not have access to run the script, ask your SharePoint Admin to run it for you.