# PowerShell script to unlock documents in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, lock

I have a Document Library in which documents are required to be checked out, but when I create a new document, as Admin, I can't to check it in because certain required fields are empty and, at the same time, I can't edit them because there is a lock created by myself.

I've read that I can't do anything by UI and I should wait 10 minutes before proceeding to saving properties. But I don't want to wait 10 minutes. I would like to write a PowerShell script to launch every time I need to unlock my documents, but I can't find something that could work with SharePoint Online... I can only find scripts for SharePoint Server.

How can I write a PowerShell script for unlocking files in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is noway to unlock a file in SharePoint online library neither through UI nor via PowerShell. You will need to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way do this in SPO using PowerShell. Similar question was discussed [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211270/unlock-sharepoint-online-file)

**Summarize answer from the above thread:**

"The technical reason behind this is not possible in SPO using PoerShell is the SOM property **locktype** is not there and neither is the method **ReleaseLock**.

So as this is not possible to release locks in SPO. If it is happening to you regularly raise a support call from your tenant admin center."

However, this is possible using SOM PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://<site>/Ringo

$list = $web.Lists[“Shared Documents”]

$item = $list.GetItemById(171)

$file = $item.File

$file

$userId = $file.LockedByUser.ID

$user = $web.AllUsers.GetByID($userId)

$impSite= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $user.UserToken);

$impWeb = $impSite.OpenWeb();

$impList = $impWeb.Lists[$list.Title]

$impItem = $impList.GetItemById($item.ID)

$impFile = $impItem.File

$impFile.ReleaseLock($impFile.LockId)
```

**Some other way of troubleshooting from your client machine:**

1. Make sure the "webclient service" on client side is running
2. Find registry key:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters on their machines.

3. Find value: SupportLocking(if no, please add), set its value to 0,want to just disable lock feature.

This disables the locking feature via the registry and does not impact any other services.

I would suggest that you test it one 1 machine first to see if it resolves the issue prior to pushing it out to all production machines.

More on this troubleshooting:

[Cannot Release Lock on SharePoint Online File](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/cannot-release-lock-on-sharepoint-online-file/m-p/59694)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cant do this on sharepoint online. But the same is achiveable in SharePoint on prem version.

For more information, refer this link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/cannot-release-lock-on-sharepoint-online-file/m-p/59694